# I am not able to select the radio button which i want i mean i want to select 5th option from radio group but its always taking 1st value

Tags: c#, leanft

i am using leanft tool to test my scripts. here is my problem, i wrote a code for selecting a radio button from radio group but it always taking the first option from radio group only but i want to select 5th option from the radio button.i am using the language C# and leanft tool

```
ITable selAcc = webdriver.getControl("demo_or.selectTable"); 
Int32 row = selAcc.Rows.Count;                  

for (int i = 1; i < row; i++)
{                       
    String acc = selAcc.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;
    if (acc.Contains(input["select@acct"]))
    {
        //int col = selAcc.Rows[i].Cells.Count;
        IRadioGroup show = selAcc.Rows[i].Equals(input["select@acct"]);
        IRadioGroup click = selAcc.Rows[i].Cells[i].FindChildren<IRadioGroup>0);
        click.Click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, post your code, as there is no way anyone can help you if they don't know what the problem is.

Comment: Are you sure this is leanft? They don't use a webdriver.

Comment: yeah i am sure, web driver is class to identify the spying objects